# Axios not working properly when using window.location.href to redirect page in react

Tags: reactjs, redirect, axios

I'm using `axios` to send requests to my server. Now I wanted to apply redirects in my frontend(React) using the `window.location.href` property. But the axios request is not being sent. I also tried to carry out an axios request and reload the page and it doesn't work even then.

```
axios.post("/api/orders",params)
  .then(res => {
    console.log("Order Placed");

    axios.delete("/api/cart/"+user_id)
    .then(res => {
      console.log("Cart Deleted");
    })
    .then(res => {
      window.location.href = '/myOrders';
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Here the axios.post works but the `axios.delete` does not. The page is getting redirected.

In the next code, again the `axios.delete` does not work.

```
axios.get('/api/getuser/')
  .then(res => {
    user_id = res.data.id;
    console.log("Id Received");
  })
  .then(res => {
    axios.delete("/api/cart/" + user_id + '/' + this.props.id)
      .then(res => {
        console.log("Product Deleted");
      })
      .then(res => {
        window.location.href = '/cart';
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Can someone please point out what the issue is or suggest a work-around?

Comment: When is the second `.then` triggered? For the `.delete`?

Comment: If delete does not work in that case also you want to redirect. Correct?

Comment: The second `.then` always fires (I think). To redirect if `delete` failed, put the redirection in `.catch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I put the redirection statement in the first then function itself. It seems all the thens are triggered simultaneously. Because of this, the second then was triggered before the first.